# How can I pass a temporary folder to a method that take a File as parameter (JUNIT)

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a method that takes File as a parameter, I want to junit test it using the @Rules temporaryFolder

Here is my method:

```
    public void processFiles(final File folder)
    {
        
        File[] fileNames = folder.listFiles();
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean isFirstFile = true;
        try
        {
            for (File file : fileNames)
            {
                    List<String> list = readContent(file);
                    list.forEach(i -> lines.add(i));
                     
                }
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is how I want to test it:

```
 @Rule
 public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

 @Test
 public void test() throws IOException {
        
        final File tempFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("tempFile.txt");
        final File tempFile2 = temporaryFolder.newFile("tempFile.txt");
     

        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempFile, "content1", "ISO-8859-1");
        
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempFile2, "content2", "ISO-8859-1");
        
        
         //Here I get an error because the parameter should be of type File and not TemporaryFolder 
        listFilesService.processFiles (temporaryFolder);
      
    }
```

Can you help me to how I should code this properly
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `temporaryFolder.getRoot()`? https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html#getRoot()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [TemporaryFolder.getRoot()](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html#getRoot()) method. Then, your test would be:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void test() throws IOException {

    final File tempFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("tempFile.txt");
    final File tempFile2 = temporaryFolder.newFile("tempFile2.txt");


    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempFile, "content1", "ISO-8859-1");

    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempFile2, "content2", "ISO-8859-1");


    // Pass the root of the TemporaryFolder which is of type File
    processFiles(temporaryFolder.getRoot());

}
```

This can be verified as working by adding a `System.out.println(file.getName());` within the `for` loop of `processFiles`. The output of the above test is:

```
tempFile.txt
tempFile2.txt
```